# SAS like operator in data step not working

Tags: sas

I want to substitute a value based on if a value contains a particular phrase.

```
data have;
if col1:='Comm' then col1='Commercial';
run;
```

Basically if col1 contains the word 'Comm', then replace the entire string with Commercial.
But it is not replacing.

Comment: `:=` is not a valid operator.  Did you mean `=:`

Comment: Looks like you may want TRANWRD() as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=:` is not a `like` or `contains` operator. Rather, it is the begins-with operator. In your case, it is looking for the exact prefix 'Comm' when reading a string from left-to-right. Use `index()` instead to find a specific set of words or substrings within a string. Here are some examples:

```
data _null_;
    length word $25.;

    put 'String: Communications';
    String = 'Communications';

    if(String =: 'Comm') then put 'The string starts with "Comm"';

    put 'String: Global Communications';
    String = 'Global Communications';

    if(String =: 'Glob') then put 'The string starts with "Glob" and not "Comm"';

    if(index(String, 'Comm') ) then put 'The string contains "Comm"';

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the begins with opertain is `=:` and linked to a where clause. Use `substr (col1,1,4)`.